GRASS r.recode lowest value given no data
I would like to recode a floating point raster using GRASS' r.recode called within a Python function. As rules file for r.recode, I am using a file created by r.quantile with the -r flag.
I am using GRASS 7.8 and Python 3.10.12 on a Linux virtual machine.
The steps are as follows:

Generate recode rules using r.quantile
Use the txt file created in r.quantile as recode rules file in r.recode

Here's the code:
import grass.script as gs
def quantrecode(rast,perc_list,filepath):
'''
:param rast: A raster image
:type rast: str
:param perc_list: A list of percentile values to be classified.
:type perc_list: list
:param filepath: A filepath where to store the quantization rules to use in r.recode.
:type filepath: str
'''
gs.run_command('g.region', raster=rast)
rastname = rast.split('@')[0]

###____________R.QUANTILE____________
# Here the quantization rules are being generated using r.quantile
quantiles = gs.read_command('r.quantile',
                            input=rast,
                            percentiles=perc_list,
                            flags='r'
                            )

# write the quantization rules to an output file so you can access them for your recode command
with open(f'{filepath}/{rastname}_quantrules.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(quantiles)

###____________R.RECODE____________
# Here the input raster is being recoded and a new raster is being created
gs.run_command('r.recode',
               input=rast,
               output=f'{rastname}_recoded_100quant', 
               rules=f'{filepath}/{rastname}_quantrules.txt'
               )

The min-max values of the raster are as follows:
min: 245771.717896522
max: 252783.592520767
The recode file reads something like this:

245771.717897:245771.717897:1
245771.717897:245817.160245:2
245817.160245:245875.266128:3
245875.266128:245947.840496:4
245947.840496:246043.219200:5
246043.219200:246142.318230:6
246142.318230:246210.874091:7
246210.874091:246282.354913:8
246282.354913:246350.803634:9
246350.803634:246425.775723:10
246425.775723:246515.724753:11
246515.724753:246599.719350:12
...

The resulting recoded raster values only start at value '2' and everything below is given a no-data value.
At first, I thought that because the recode rules file is rounding some of the decimal points, it is not fetching the lowest raster value. So I have tried to circumvent that doing:

Adding a line to the recode file of pattern


*:old_val:new_val         (interval [inf, old_val]) 
as specified in the GRASS manual to fetch all the lowest values


Using a mapcalc if() expression reading the info from the recode file, again with a leading *:VALUE:VALUE line in the txt file.

Both unfortunately with the same frustrating result of lowest values receiving no-data in the recoded raster.
Anybody have any ideas what is happening or what I'm doing wrong?
As a side note: my handling of file names is probably not ideal, but I'm new to coding, so please forgive the ugly code. I'm pretty sure it's also possible to parse the output of r.quantile more directly r.recode, but with my limited experience I haven't figured out how to do that, yet, and I'm not sure that would give me a different result. I don't think either of these issues are too relevant for my problem though.
